# Get a session back from a class in another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class where i am setting and getting a session. I am fairly new to C#
How can i retrieve a session from my class in another class?

Here is my session class.

```
public class JobApplicantSession
{

    public JobApplication ApplicationSession
    {

           get
       {
           JobApplication _application = (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];

           return _application;

        }
      set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = value;
         // Session["Application"] = value;
       }
    }
```

I am able to set the session. However, getting it i dont know how.
I made an object of the class and the object can access the function name ApplicationSession

```
JobApplicantSession sess = new JobApplicantSession();
sess.ApplicationSession
```

I know it probobly depends on what i need to do with it, but i just wanted to verify its setting and getting properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter will throw an exception when there is nothing in session so you need to deal with this.

So you need to check if the session value exists

```
get
{
  if ( HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] != null )
    return (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
  return null;
}
set
{
   ...
}
```

You might not use the setter at all..

```
get
    {
      if ( HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] == null )
          HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = new JobApplication();
      return (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
    }
```

Or..

```
 get
        {
          if ( HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] == null )
              HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = JobApplicationFactory.CreateApplication();
          return (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
        }
```

Where `JobApplicationFactory` might be a class which creates a `JobApplication` object

**EDIT**
I realized I didn't answer the question..

To call the getter from another class..

```
public class JobApplicant
{
   private JobApplication application;
   public void AddCurrentApplication()
   {
       var jas = new JobApplicationSession();
       application = jas.ApplicationSession;
   }
}
```

Comment: instead of checking the 'null' values can't we just 'as' cast? like 'HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] as JobApplication' ?

Comment: Yes. But I'm going on the idea that, in this case, either the object exists in session or not. If does exist, I know that the object is JobApplication type, so I use the explicit cast, because is faster. I would use the "as" operator when I'm not sure about the type of the object.

Comment: so, how can i gt the session from another class?